# Can I construct a variable's name from strings in Python?

Tags: python, variables, arguments

I was wondering if I can pass an argument to a function by passing it a different argument that constructs the first argument's name from strings. Basically `cut(arg)` to be the same as `cut(clip_a)`?

```
str = ['a', 'b']

clip_a = ['vacation', 'work']
clib_b = ['gym', 'court']

arg = f'clip_{str[0]}'

def cut(clip):
    clip[0] = 'sauna'

cut(arg)
```

Comment: If the linked question doesn't help you, you can access variables by their string name with `globals()[name]`. `globals()` returns a dict-like object that contains the global variables. Similarly, `locals()` gives access to local variables. If `clip` is a string name then you could change your function to contain `globals()[clip][0] = "sauna"`

Comment: Thank you @MichaelCG8 You helped me a lot with this.